# Is Accelerated Failure Time (AFT) method acceptable for answering my study question (an example)?

Tags: r, survival-analysis, survival

I need to conduct an adjusted survival analysis, however, Cox PH assumption was not met and data stratification isn't a good solution as one of my study groups already has a small number of patients. Thus, I tried to fit my first AFT model, however, I am not sure if everything is fine. Is the following approach OK for answering my study question?

**Study question:** to compared adjusted survival of two patient groups, A (n=11000) and B (n=50)

**Follow up time:** 460 days

**Variables used for adjusting:** age (50-100), sex (m/f), comorbidity(integer, 0-12)

**The approach I used (my current best understanding of AFT)**

**1. I run AFT models with different distributions (here I only show two models to reduce the length of this post)**

```
library(flexsurv)
fit_genf = flexsurvreg(Surv(time, status) ~ group, dist="genf", data = data)
fit_llogis = flexsurvreg(Surv(time, status) ~ group, dist="llogis", data = data)
```

**2. Then I plot the models to assess their fit with the data and choose the best**

```
plot(fit_genf)
```

[Plot: Generalised F distribution AFT model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jK0XV.png)

```
plot(fit_llogis)
```

[Plot: Logistic scale distribution AFT model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kSHyh.png)

**3. Then I check their log-likelihoods and choose the best**

```
fit_genf$loglik
```

-29540.38

```
fit_llogis$loglik
```

-29748.55

**4. RESULT: Generalised F distribution AFT modelling (fit_genf) is an acceptable method for my analysis since this had the best fit and better log-likelihood. Or is something wrong in my approach (large AIC number, log-likelihood etc)?**

Full fit_genf model summary:

```
Call:
flexsurvreg(formula = Surv(time, status) ~ group, data = data, 
    dist = "genf")

Estimates: 
        data mean  est       L95%      U95%      se        exp(est)
mu            NA    4.82150   4.29511   5.34788   0.26857        NA
sigma         NA    2.37833   1.89590   2.98351   0.27509        NA
Q             NA   -2.79284  -3.71926  -1.86641   0.47267        NA
P             NA    2.22999   1.05947   4.69368   0.84675        NA
groupB   0.00433    0.62147  -0.29332   1.53627   0.46674   1.86167
        L95%      U95%    
mu            NA        NA
sigma         NA        NA
Q             NA        NA
P             NA        NA
groupB   0.74578   4.64721

N = 11541,  Events: 3851,  Censored: 7690
Total time at risk: 4024558
Log-likelihood = -29540.38, df = 5
AIC = 59090.77
```

Comment: You'd be better off asking this question over at the [Stats stackexchange](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) website.

Comment: Agree. Voting to migrate.

Comment: Thank you! I'll do so!

Comment: It's here now: [link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/460285/is-this-a-correct-method-to-confirm-accelerated-failure-time-aft-methods-suit)